# Как праивильно использовать gridview с данными в scrollview

Tags: java, android

Вообщем,необходимо сделать так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как должно работать:
фигуры (круги) должны пролистываться посредством scroll, как  правильно это сделать...пока только тогадки,выручайте 
т.е порядок отрисовки и вывода должен быть неизменяемым, т.е сначало 4 круга ниже 3 круга,потом опять 4 и т.д около 40 ш.т. Круги т.е(изображения,Imageview) будт кликабельными и будут выполнять свои уникальные действия, на каждый круг своя опред. задача, отрисовывать думаю через цикл ...но опять проблема в реализации,надеюсь все доступно объяснил.

Добавил разметку:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/lldinamik"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="3dp"
android:paddingRight="3dp"
android:paddingTop="3dp"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">





<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_stop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/stop_button"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/play_button"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sbar"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:max="100"

        android:progress="0"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPlayer"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text=" "
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вашу задачу можно решить при помощи `RecyclerView` с `GridLayoutManager`.

Comment: @ s8am
а не направите в нужное русло?)

Comment: Для начала можете построить просто некоторый список на основе `RecyclerView` с `LinearLayoutManager`, разберитесь как там все работает. Потом постройте таблицу на основе `RecyclerView` с `GridLayoutManager`. А после этого можете приступить к решению Вашей задачи. Давать какое-то конкретное решение Вашей задачи я смысла не вижу, так как если Вам будет необходимо что-то поменять, то посыпется куча вопросов (ответы на которые можно получить как раз решив две первоначальные задачи).

Comment: @ s8am
на словах все всегда легко...

Comment: А я и не говорил, что будет легко (но и не факт, что будет сложно, все зависит от уровня Ваших знаний). Но, я считаю, что выполнять данную задачу нужно именно в таком порядке.

Comment: @ s8am
если планиурется список из imageview то и заполнять imageview?

Comment: Вы про разметку каждого элемента? Если да, то совсем необязательно. Можно (и скорее даже нужно) обернуть `ImageView` чем-нибудь типа `RalativeLayout`.

Comment: @s8am
если вам не сложно,пожалуйста, накидайте,а точнее на основе моей разметки укажите чт окуда,спасибо...

Comment: Чуть позже постараюсь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Сразу оговорюсь, что исходную задачу решаю с нуля, не используя Ваши «наработки».*

Создаете новый проект в **Android Studio**. Далее подключаете `RecyclerView`:

**File** – **Project structure** – **Modules** (app) – **Dependencies** – **Add** (+) – **Library dependency** – **recyclerview-v7** – **Ok** – **Ok**

Это можно сделать по-другому, но в данном случае это не важно.

Добавляете layout-файлы:

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/circle_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_circle_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Add circle"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**item_circle.xml** – layout одной ячейки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Создаете класс `CircleItem` – элемент одной ячейки :

```
public class CircleItem {

    private int mResId;

    public CircleItem(int resId) {
        mResId = resId;
    }

    public int getResId() {
        return mResId;
    }

    public void setResId(int resId) {
        mResId = resId;
    }
}
```

Создаете `ViewHolder`:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CircleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView mItemImageView;

    public CircleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mItemImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image_view);
    }

    public ImageView getItemImageView() {
        return mItemImageView;
    }
}
```

Создаете адаптер для `RecyclerView`:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CircleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CircleViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<CircleItem> mData;

    public CircleAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mData = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public CircleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_circle, parent, false);
        return new CircleViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CircleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int resId = mData.get(position).getResId();
        holder.getItemImageView().setImageDrawable(mContext.getDrawable(resId));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public void addItem(int resId) {
        mData.add(new CircleItem(resId));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

И, наконец, `MainActivity`:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mCircleRecyclerView;
    private Button mAddCircleButton;

    private Random mRandom;
    private CircleAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRandom = new Random();

        mCircleRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.circle_recycler_view);
        mAddCircleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_circle_button);

        mAdapter = new CircleAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 12);

        gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                switch (position % 7) {
                    case 0:
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                    case 3:
                        return 3;
                    case 4:
                    case 5:
                    case 6:
                        return 4;
                }
                return 3;
            }
        });

        mCircleRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        mCircleRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mAddCircleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                switch (mRandom.nextInt(6)) {
                    case 0:
                        mAdapter.addItem(R.mipmap.ic_circle_one);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        mAdapter.addItem(R.mipmap.ic_circle_two);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        mAdapter.addItem(R.mipmap.ic_circle_three);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        mAdapter.addItem(R.mipmap.ic_circle_four);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        mAdapter.addItem(R.mipmap.ic_circle_five);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        mAdapter.addItem(R.mipmap.ic_circle_six);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        mAdapter.addItem(R.mipmap.ic_circle_seven);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

В итоге получаете вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По нажатию на кнопку, добавляется новая иконка, в соответствии с желаемым алгоритмом.

Единственное что, строки, которые содержат три элемента, выглядят не очень, но это можно исправить и эту задачу я оставляю Вам.

Можно исправить, но получается не то ,что хотелось бы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]